# Giving a cell a maximum, but having the overflow end up in other cells

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a value in a cell of `$34,009,345`. I'm trying to get it to split unevenly over three cells. But there are maximums to the first two cells. I need the first cell to have a max of `$4,500,000`, the second cell to have a max of `$3,000,000` and then the third doesn't have a max, it's where all the overflow goes. There is a way apparently where when I type in that `$34,009,345` that it will split through those three cells. Help?

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like:

```
     A               B                  C                  D
-------------------------------------------------------------------
$34,009,345     $4,500,000         $3,000,000        $26,509,345
$34,009,345 =MIN(A1,4500000)  =MIN(A1-B1,3000000)  =MAX(0,A1-B1-C1)
```

The formula in B will grab whichever is smaller the value in A or 4,500,000:

```
=MIN(A1,4500000)
```

The next formula looks at the difference from A to B and uses that or 3,000,000 whichever is smallest:

```
=MIN(A1-B1,3000000)
```

Then we can dump the difference in D (or 0 if B and C took care of everything):

```
=MAX(0,A1-B1-C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a macro approach for the problem :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errH
    Dim dblAmount As Double
    Const sCellAddress1 As String = "A1"    ' <- 1st cell where you enter the nuber
    Const sCellAddress2 As String = "B1"    ' <- 2nd cell
    Const sCellAddress3 As String = "C1"    ' <- 3rd cell
    Const MaxCell1 As Double = 4500000      ' <- Max value for the 1st cell
    Const MaxCell2 As Double = 3000000      ' <- Max value for the 2nd cell

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sCellAddress1)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'The main function
        Me.Range(sCellAddress2).Value = vbNullString
        Me.Range(sCellAddress3).Value = vbNullString
        dblAmount = Target.Value
        If dblAmount > MaxCell1 Then
            Me.Range(sCellAddress1).Value = MaxCell1
            dblAmount = dblAmount - MaxCell1
            Me.Range(sCellAddress2).Value = dblAmount
            If dblAmount > MaxCell2 Then
                Me.Range(sCellAddress2).Value = MaxCell2
                dblAmount = dblAmount - MaxCell2
                Me.Range(sCellAddress3).Value = dblAmount
            End If
        End If

    End If
errH:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, , "Error"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Installing:** Open VBE > open the worksheet module in Project Window > paste the code.
**Usage:** Enter a value in the first specified cell (`A1` the default value; you can change it in the code).